# future functions keep repeating

Tags: dart, flutter

am trying to read and write in files in my flutter app .. like this:

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
print('hi');
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
final path = await _localPath;
File f = File('$path/mypollshash.txt');
if (f.existsSync()) {
  print('exists');
  String contents = await f.readAsString();
  content = contents;
  fetchHash();
} else {
  print('not exists');
  fetch();
}
return f;
}

Future checkfileexist() async {
try {
  final file = await _localFile;
  String contents = await file.readAsString();
  content = contents;
} catch (e) {
  //return 'nothing';
}
}

Future<File> writehash(String hash) async {
final file = await _localFile;
return file.writeAsString('$hash', mode: FileMode.write);
}

Future<File> get _localjson async {
final path = await _localPath;
return File('$path/mypolls.json');
}

Future<File> writejson(String json) async {
final file = await _localjson;
return file.writeAsString('$json', mode: FileMode.write);
}

readjson() async {
try {
  final file = await _localjson;
  String contents = await file.readAsString();
  content = contents;
  setState(() {
    polls = pollsFromJson(content);
    isloading = false;
  });
  writejson(pollsToJson(polls));
  writehash(polls.hash);
  print('here');
  //  return contents;
  } catch (e) {
  fetch();
  print('there');
  print(e);
  // If we encounter an error, return 0
  //return 'nothing';
}
}

fetch() async {
String data =
    await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/mypolls.json");
setState(() {
  polls = pollsFromJson(data);
  isloading = false;
});
writejson(pollsToJson(polls));
writehash(polls.hash);
}

fetchHash() async {
String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
    .loadString("assets/pollshash.json");
print(content);
final pollshash = pollshashFromJson(data);
if (content == pollshash.hash) {
  print('take from the saved json');
  readjson();
} else {
  print('call api');
  fetch();
}
}
```

and then am calling it here:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
checkfileexist();
}
```

this works fine .. but the method will keep called even when i go to another page and will get this printed over and over again:

> I/flutter (17060): hi
>   I/flutter (17060): here
>   I/flutter (17060): exists
>   I/flutter (17060): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter (17060): take from the saved json

I want this to be called only once .. how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

InitState is not called once it's normal. Instead you can do it with multiple solutions. 
Create an attributes in your component to memorize if you already did your checks like this

```
class MyComponentState ... {
  bool hasChecked = false;
  bool isFileExists = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(!hasChecked) {
      this.hasChecked = true;
      this.isFileExists = checkfileexist();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's possible then that you are creating multiple instance of your component. Check it

Comment: how to check this?

Comment: add a log in your component constructor for exemple (in state and component as you need to be sure you are not creating multiple state too)